# Incorrect Syntax near Order with IF SELECT INTO Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-order-by

So I'll post my SQL code below (actually just the part that is failing) and this is for a SQL Server as well:

```
SELECT @newPID = (SELECT policy_id FROM #StatusTable);
SELECT @newTXN = (SELECT txn_number FROM #StatusTable);

IF (@newPID IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #StatusTable 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
             id, policy_product_id, txn_number, agent_id, user_id, old_status_id, 
             new_status_id, status_update_date, status_type_id, notes, policy_id
         FROM  sales_blotter_status_changes
         WHERE (policy_id = @newPID)
         ORDER BY status_update_date DESC)
END 
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #StatusTable 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
             id, policy_product_id, txn_number, agent_id, user_id, old_status_id, 
             new_status_id, status_update_date, status_type_id, notes, policy_id
         FROM  sales_blotter_status_changes
         WHERE (txn_number = @newTXN)
         ORDER BY status_update_date DESC)
END
```

So if you look through this basically what I'm trying to create a temp table based on whether or not a specific field from a previous table is Null or not. When I run this query I get a incorrect syntax error that states the problem is next to ORDER (even though it doesn't state I'm pretty sure it would be the first one). Can someone take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong, I've been working on this for about 4 hours and I just can't find the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that subqueries require an alias in sql-server.  So, try this quick fix:

```
SELECT @newPID = (SELECT policy_id FROM #StatusTable);
SELECT @newTXN = (SELECT txn_number FROM #StatusTable);

IF (@newPID IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO #StatusTable (SELECT TOP (1) id, policy_product_id, txn_number, agent_id, user_id, old_status_id, new_status_id, status_update_date, status_type_id, notes, policy_id
FROM  sales_blotter_status_changes
WHERE (policy_id = @newPID)
ORDER BY status_update_date DESC) t
END ELSE BEGIN
SELECT * INTO #StatusTable (SELECT TOP (1) id, policy_product_id, txn_number, agent_id, user_id, old_status_id, new_status_id, status_update_date, status_type_id, notes, policy_id
FROM  sales_blotter_status_changes
WHERE (txn_number = @newTXN)
ORDER BY status_update_date DESC) t
END
```

By the way, you don't need the subquery.  In fact, you don't even need two queries.  You can write the logic as:

```
SELECT TOP (1) id, policy_product_id, txn_number, agent_id, user_id, old_status_id, new_status_id, status_update_date, status_type_id, notes, policy_id
INTO #StatusTable 
FROM  sales_blotter_status_changes
WHERE (@newPID is not null and policy_id = @newPID) or (@newPID is null and txn_number = @newTXN)
ORDER BY status_update_date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that was the problem and the more simplified second solution is even better.